# Android Subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-billing

1.Is there a way by which we can make the subscription permanent?Once the user subscribe for the app he will be able to use it for free as long as he/she wishes.

2.Also can we limit the monthly subscription to a certain period.i.e. the user must subscribe for minimum of 12 months?

Please guide

Comment: this may helps you http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Answer (score 1):

1. than it is not a subscription, just an in-app purchase
2. no, you can use 1 year subscriptions only

Answer (score 0):

1) as @xnagyg said, you should represent such a product as an 'in-app purchase' rather than a 'subscription'. Subscriptions by nature can be renewed (paid for repeatedly to resubscribe). Note that Subscriptions autorenew by default (you have no option there, the User must cancel to stop it autorenewing).

2) Currently, the Google Play Developer Console allows these Billing periods:

- Weekly
- Monthly
- 3 months
- 6 months
- Yearly
- Seasonal